# Influxdb - Query returning no results

Tags: influxdb

I am at a bit of a loss trying to figure out what is going on here:

I get results for this query:

```
SELECT value  FROM "measures" WHERE time <= 1465195336002ms ORDER BY time desc

{
    "results": [
        {
            "statement_id": 0,
            "series": [
                {
                    "name": "measures",
                    "columns": [
                        "time",
                        "value"
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        [
                            1465195336000,
                            87.4
                        ],
                        [
                            1464596862000,
                            86.66
                        ],
                        [
                            1464070337000,
                            86.64
                        ],
                        [
                            1463985100000,
                            86.77
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

All well and good, as expected.

But if I issue the following query, I get no results. Clearly this should match the same rows as above minus the first result:

```
SELECT value  FROM "measures" WHERE time <= 1464596862000ms ORDER BY time desc

{
    "results": [
        {
            "statement_id": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, although far from obvious, it seems that this behaviour occurs when there is more than 1 measurement recorded for a given time period.